# auditd Syscalls - difference between chown and chownat?

Tags: linux, audit

I am trying to get through auditd and it confuses me sometimes.
For example, if I want to monitor if the owner of a file changes, I would use something like

```
-a always,exit -F path=/home/user/test.txt -S chmod -k changed
```

But I have seen that there are different chmod system calls, fchmod, fchmodat.
Would I need to specify all of them? Or is one of them enough.

I (somewhat) realise the difference from a programming poin of view, but is this relevant for auditd?

For example, if I use chmod, can it still happen that the owner is changed without auditd noticing it?

Or another example: Deleting a directory. rmdir, unlink, unlinkat.

What should I choose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to implement security auditing then yes you should audit all these system calls.

For example if you read [openSCAP Security Guide for RHEL 7](https://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-rhel7-guide-C2S.html#xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_audit_rules_dac_modification_fchownat) you'll see that you should audit `fchown`, `fchownat`, `lchown`, `chmod`, `fchmod`  etc.

Comment: Could I alternatively just do an -S all? I guess this would be bad for permance?

Comment: Audit every single system calls? Performance should be bad indeed! I've never done that but you have to think about what you will do with the logs: reports, alerts... I don't think it will be very useful if you log everything?

Comment: Right. I just meant that in regards to know which chmod/chown version I should use. Would it be the same to just use -p wa (which records changes), or would this also internally use -S all?

Comment: A chmod or chown is an operation on the filesystem, not on the file, so it wouldn't be audited if you record changes on files. If you really don't want to be too verbose in the configuration, I guess you'll have to use -S all. But I think it is better to have multiple rules and have only relevant information in the logs.